# Possible to call a function inside BoundColumn.DataField?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, boundcolumn, datafield

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="pos" HeaderText="Principal Office" />
```

would it be possible to somehow...

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="postProccess(pos)" HeaderText="Principal Office" />
```

...so I could modify the value as needed?

CRAP:

```
A field or property with the name 'postProcess(pos)' was not found on the selected data source.
```

Anyone know how I can override that thing or something??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full snippet you'd want to use for your template column...

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Principal Office">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <%# postProcess(Eval("pos")) %>
   <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

use an [`<asp:templatecolumn>`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211031102330/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032203-1.aspx) and do the post processing in the [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) event